# Deleting a node from B tree

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, tree, b-tree

min no of keys = 2 
max no of keys = 5

```
                            P

              CL                           TX
       AB    DEJK    NO               QRS    UV    YZ
```

Deleting key D:

```
                    CLPTX
       AB    EJK    NO   QRS    UV    YZ
```

this Answer is as per `Introduction to Algorithms by thomas H . Cormen`
pg. no 501

it says: *this is case 3b: the recursion cannot descend to node CL because it has only 2 keys so we need to push P down and merge it with CL and TX to form CLPTX the n we delete D from leaf (case1)*

but I Think this answer is also fine:

```
                            P

              CL                           TX
       AB    EJK    NO               QRS    UV    YZ
```

because leaf node EJK still have 3 keys satisfying min key constrainsts.

Please explain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the deleting algorithm goes from top to bottom, and therefore it cannot know if the leaves have enough or not.

to make sure the algorithm works every time, it was decided that cells that have minimum keys (but legal) along the way from the top, will be merged. that's because if the leaves will need a "donation" from their parents, their parent will be able to provide them.

note: i said "leaves" to simplify things, but it also apply to every cell along the way.

note2: that's why in `insert` you do the opposite even if in a specific cases you may not have to.

Comment: updated my question with 1 more case i think this will explain me more clearly if you explain this case

Comment: please break answer into steps

Comment: imagine the recursion gets to the leaf, and then see its already at minimum keys. so you should go to its parent and take one key right? and what if the parent doesn't have enough to give (also minimum) then what? go to his parent? and his parent and his grandparent.... and so on? so potentially every recursive call go up all the way to the root. what will happen to the run-time in this case?